# Oracle Apex Login Page

Tags: oracle, authentication, oracle-apex

I'm looking to create a login page based on the username and password in one of the tables used in an Oracle Apex application. At the minute I can't find any information on how to do this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to change the login page, all you need to do is implement a custom **Authentication Scheme**.

All you need to do is create a function (e.g. `FUNCTION authenticate(username_in IN VARCHAR2, password_in IN VARCHAR2) RETURN BOOLEAN ...`) that returns TRUE if the username/password is correct, and FALSE otherwise.

e.g. as described [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc/doc.42/e35125/sec_authentication.htm#HTMDB12003), [here](http://allthingsoracle.com/custom-authentication-in-apex/) and [here](http://www.oraclecafe.com/2013/04/11/apex-custom-authentication-scheme/).